# OpenCMS - Possible to turn off cookies for a folder with static content?

Tags: opencms

With OpenCMS version 7.x, is it possible to specify a folder as not requiring cookies to be served with its contents, e.g. images etc that don't need cookies to bloat the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an OpenCms feature, you'd have to configure this in your application server.